# Level shiffter (3.3V / 5V) for controlling transistors

Tags: arduino, transistors, level-shifting

Is it possible to control the base of the transistor using the level shift chip (3.3V / 5V)?
I want to use the [SN74AHCT125](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Texas-Instruments-TI-SN74AHCT125DR_C155176.pdf) level shift chip.

[Transistor BC337-16](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/395/BC337-16%20Series_B14-521022.pdf)

Comment: It is possible to get bad results too unless you are more specific on your configuration and output spec limits.,

Comment: Please edit your question to include a schematic of what you're really trying to do.  As pointed out in the answer, a level-shifter is almost certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There generally is no need to use a level shifter to control a BJT transistor, as long as the high output level is higher than the required \$V_{\rm BE}\$ (1.2V for your BC337-16 transistor, with \$I_{\rm C} = 300 \rm mA\$ and \$V_{\rm CE} = 1 \rm V\$). WHat are you trying/willing to do?